# nmake: using environment variables and falling back to default values

Tags: windows, makefile, environment-variables, nmake

In an `nmake` Makefile, i would like to set a variable to the value of an environment variable, but provide a default value if the envvar is not set.

With GNU make I would use the `?=` syntax:

```
VCINSTALLDIR ?= "%ProgramFiles%\\Microsoft Visual Studio 3.14\\VC"
```

S if the VCINSTALLDIR variable is set as an environment variable, the makefile uses that value, but falls back to the value provided.

Unfortunately `nmake` cannot handle the `?=` syntax.
Which other options do I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that the trick is to use `IFNDEF`:

```
!IFNDEF VCINSTALLDIR
VCINSTALLDIR = "%ProgramFiles%\\Microsoft Visual Studio 3.14\\VC"
!ENDIF
```